# Calculate crc32 with seed using Python

Tags: python, linux-kernel, crc32

In `linux/crc32.h` there is crc32 that define:

```
crc32(seed, data, length)
```

How can I calculate crc32 with seed using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the docs:

```py
import zlib
help(zlib.crc32)
```

```
Help on built-in function crc32 in module zlib:

crc32(data, value=0, /)
    Compute a CRC-32 checksum of data.

      value
        Starting value of the checksum.

    The returned checksum is an integer.
```

`Data` are the same between the two implementations. `Seed` in the C implementation is `value` in the Python implementation. Note that it defaults to 0 in `zlib.crc32`.